# Table Cell color highlight and un-highlight on select jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, cell, highlight

I have designed a tabular calendar with bunch of TD / TR elements under table body.

I want a interaction on each day of table like when I click on one td element (which is one day) it will be highlighted with border and when I moved cursor and click other day this day will be highlighted and previous one will be un-highlighted . My code is like this, but the problem is the .off click function. It is not unhighlighting so all table cells become highlighted and persists. How could I fix this using jQuery?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

 $("td.PTDC").on("click",function(){  

  $(this).css("background-color", "#0093e0");
  $(this).css("padding", "5px");
  console.log("onclick");
    }); 

 $("tbody").off("click",function(){  
  $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
  $(this).css("padding", "0px");
  console.log("offclick");
    }); 
});

    </script>
```

============================
I observed in source that Before click it has :

```
<td class="PTDC PTLC OOCT" id="db_saw_1883_7_1_6" style="border-style:none;border-right:solid 1px #DADADB;border-bottom:solid 1px #DADADB;">
```

And after click it has :

```
<td class="PTDC OOCT" id="db_saw_1883_7_1_5" style="border-style: none solid solid none; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-color: rgb(218, 218, 219); border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: rgb(218, 218, 219); background-color: rgb(0, 147, 224); padding: 5px;">
```

But since all my 30 days in calendar is like one day each td elements it is difficult to de-associate the format when other td elements clicked.

Comment: The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 2

OP is using a primitive application that class styles cannot override. I have deduced from various clues about Tools (OP is vague) it:
 = generates...HTML tables
 - it uses inline styles 
 - if so then that would explain why styling with classes is incredibly difficult.
 - Inline styles (ex. `<div style='color:blue'>`) can't be overridden by rulesets in a stylesheet or even from a `<style>` block with !important being the exception. **Demo 3** will demonstrate 2 ways to deal with inline style attributes.

```
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $('td').each(function(idx, cell) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    cell.style.borderColor = '#000';
    if ($(cell).hasClass('today')) {
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)';
      cell.style.borderColor = '#aae1ff';
    }
  });
  tgt.style.backgroundColor = '#0093e0';
  tgt.style.borderColor = '#09e';
});
```

1. `e.target` is the `<td>` that the user has clicked.
2. `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` prevents the event from bubbling and being heard by any other listener as well.
3. `$('td').each(function(idx, cell) {...` Every `<td>` will have a function ran on it.
4. Each cell (i.e. `<td>`) will have their inline style attributes set to:

   ```
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';

    cell.style.borderColor = '#000';
   ```
5. If this particular cell has the `.today` class, then:

   ```
   if ($(cell).hasClass('today')) {
     cell.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)';
     cell.style.borderColor = '#aae1ff';
   }
   ```
6. When the `for` loop is complete, change `e.target` style:

   ```
    tgt.style.backgroundColor = '#0093e0';

    tgt.style.borderColor = '#09e';
   ```

---

### Update 1

I misinterpreted the question: OP's desired behavior is that only one cell at a time can have the `.lit` class. It's an easy modification using `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()` and [**`.not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/). See Demo 2.

```
/* Delegate the click event on all
|| td (cell).
|| Remove the .lit class on every <td>
|| and add .lit class for the clicked <td>
*/
$('td').on('click', function() {
    var that = $(this);
  $('td').not(that).removeClass('lit');
    that.addClass('lit');
});
```

## Problem

> *"...but the problem is the `.off` click function. It is not unhighlighting so all table cells become highlighted and persists. How could I fix this using jQuery?"*

The behavior OP mentions is called toggling which is the ability to go back and forth between 2 *"states"* (e.g. state is in *off* and *on*, or *light* and *dark*, etc). In this case it is the toggling of 2 backgrounds.

The [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is a function that adds an event listener ***on*** any given individual or group of elements (e.g. a `$('td')`).

The [**`.off()`**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method is a function that removes an event listener ***off*** of any given individual or group of elements. `.off()` does not undo whatever `.on()` has done, `.off()` ***removes*** `.on()`. So every `<td>` clicked then lost the event listener registered to it.

---

## Solution

1. Avoid using `.css()` method for styling a group of elements
2. It's far more efficient to manipulate classes. In this demo `.lit` is the other state and the default state is `<td>` without class `.lit`
3. [**`.toggleClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) is the method used to do this.

---

The primary function in the following demo addresses the issue explained by OP.
As a bonus I have added the following features:

- Highlights today's cell
- Generates a number for each day of the month

**Details are commented in demo**

### Demo 1 (Toggle Class)

```js
// Make a Date Object
var d = new Date();
// Get today's day as a number
var today = d.getDate();

/* Find the cell at the index number 
|| (which is eq -1) and add thr .today class
*/
$('td').eq(today - 1).addClass('today');

/* On each cell, add the day number, unless
|| the cell has class .empty
*/ // Note: the syntax of string on line 19
// is ES6 Template Literal see post for ref.
$('td').each(function(index, day) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('empty')) {
    return
  }
  $(this).append(`<b>${index+1}</b>`);
});

/* Delegate the click event on all
|| td (cell).
|| callback on each td is to 
|| toggle the .lit class
*/
$('td').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('lit');
});
```

```css
.month {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border: 3px outset grey
}

caption {
  font-variant: small-caps
}

.month td {
  border: 2px inset black;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.lit {
  background-color: #0093e0;
  border-color: #09e;
}

td.today {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  border-color: #aae1ff;
}

td.today.lit {
  background: tomato;
  border-color: red
}

td b {
  font-size: .3em;
  color: #123;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -7px 0 0 -5px;
}

td.today b {
  color: #fff
}

.empty {
  /* Prevents any mouse events 
|| i.e unclickable
*/
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<table class='month'>
  <caption>October</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SUN</th>
      <th>MON</th>
      <th>TUE</th>
      <th>WED</th>
      <th>THU</th>
      <th>FRI</th>
      <th>SAT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='empty' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Demo 2 (Exclusive Class)

```js
// Make a Date Object
var d = new Date();
// Get today's day as a number
var today = d.getDate();

/* Find the cell at the index number 
|| (which is eq -1) and add thr .today class
*/
$('td').eq(today - 1).addClass('today');

/* On each cell, add the day number, unless
|| the cell has class .empty
*/// Note: the syntax of string on line 19
// is ES6 Template Literal see post for ref.
$('td').each(function(index, day) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('empty')) {
    return
  }
  $(this).append(`<b>${index+1}</b>`);
});

/* Delegate the click event on all
|| td (cell).
|| Remove the .lit class on every <td>
|| and add .lit class for the clicked <td>
*/
$('td').on('click', function() {
 var that = $(this);
  $('td').not(that).removeClass('lit');
 that.addClass('lit');
});
```

```css
.month {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border: 3px outset grey
}

caption {
  font-variant: small-caps
}

.month td {
  border: 2px inset black;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.lit {
  background-color: #0093e0;
  border-color: #09e;
}

td.today {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  border-color: #aae1ff;
}

td.today.lit {
  background: tomato;
  border-color: red
}

td b {
  font-size: .3em;
  color: #123;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -7px 0 0 -5px;
}

td.today b {
  color: #fff
}

.empty {
/* Prevents any mouse events 
|| i.e unclickable
*/
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<table class='month'>
  <caption>October</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SUN</th>
      <th>MON</th>
      <th>TUE</th>
      <th>WED</th>
      <th>THU</th>
      <th>FRI</th>
      <th>SAT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='empty' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Demo 3

```js
// Make a Date Object
var d = new Date();
// Get today's day as a number
var today = d.getDate();

/* Find the cell at the index number 
|| (which is eq -1) and add thr .today class
*/
$('td').eq(today - 1).addClass('today');

/* On each cell, add the day number, unless
|| the cell has class .empty
*/ // Note: the syntax of string on line 19
// is ES6 Template Literal see post for ref.
$('td').each(function(index, day) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('empty')) {
    return
  }
  $(this).append(`<b>${index+1}</b>`);
});

/* Delegate the click event on all
|| td (cell).
|| See post update for details
|| 
*/
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $('td').each(function(idx, cell) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    cell.style.borderColor = '#000';
    if ($(cell).hasClass('today')) {
      cell.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)';
      cell.style.borderColor = '#aae1ff';
    }
  });
  tgt.style.backgroundColor = '#0093e0';
  tgt.style.borderColor = '#09e';
});
```

```css
.month {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border: 3px outset grey
}

caption {
  font-variant: small-caps
}

.month td {
  border: 2px inset black;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.lit {
  background-color: #0093e0;
  border-color: #09e;
}

td.today {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  border-color: #aae1ff;
}

td.today.lit {
  background: tomato;
  border-color: red
}

td b {
  font-size: .3em;
  color: #123;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -7px 0 0 -5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}

td.today b {
  color: #fff
}

.empty {
  /* Prevents any mouse events 
|| i.e unclickable
*/
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<table class='month'>
  <caption>October</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SUN</th>
      <th>MON</th>
      <th>TUE</th>
      <th>WED</th>
      <th>THU</th>
      <th>FRI</th>
      <th>SAT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class='empty' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>














<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Reference

**Time**
   [**Date()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), 
    [**.getDate()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

**DOM Collection**
   [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), 
   [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

**Class Manipulation**
  [**.toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), 
   [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), 
   [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), 
   [**.hasClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

**Event Delegation**
[**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/), 
[**.off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

**Miscellaneous**
   [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), 
   [**ES6 Template Literals**](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-genius-of-template-strings-in-es6--cms-24915)
   [**`.not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Well @zer00ne . But here is my problem . I can still replicate what are showing here but instead of keeping the blue color on each day for each click I want it to go off when I click on different day . Basically when I click 15th it highlights and when I click 20th it should white background for 15th but blue for 20th . So I guess I dont want toggling. Also when I click 15th while all other days are white I want 15th to highlight and when I click 15th again and again I want this to keep it blue and not white. I am pretty sure a modification of your code can help on that . thank you

Comment: @pauldx a simple modification as you have said, review Demo 2.

Comment: Actually I am trying to maniputing the code generated by Tools so below code works fine ... Unfortunately I can't use your code to refer from class and turn on and off ...basically tools existing code not liking it :   The only problem I am getting is : when I click other cell its not removing previous cell color : is there any other workaround with css and if I am missing something:  $(document).ready(function() {
  
 $("td.PTDC").on("click", function() {
 $( this ).css({
      "background-color": "#0093e0",
      "border": "10px"
    });   });

Comment: That statement looks correct I believe, except maybe use `"border-width"` What Tools? You mean the console?

Comment: Are you talking about the current day? The behavior you are referring to is it occurring in the stack snippet? That's the only environment I can help you with. Any other factors you introduce to my code must be considered a likely cause. I do not know the full extent of your environment or was aware that a "Tool" is involved...very vague info ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you can't hook into .class (is Tools a propriety application from 1990?) then `$("td.PTDC").` might not be viable selector, nor could jQuery be very helpful at all. If what you say about this Tools is correct, then I advise that you use a browser like Chrome.

Comment: @pauldx OK, finally figured out what's wrong, review **Update 2** and **Demo 3**

Comment: most of the demo is helpful but the killer clue gave by other user is !important. I am using tools which is oracle software with lot of predefined js / css / html ...tweaking it is hard and injecting you code onto it. but your demo is all useful . I use toggleclass but used !important to override the color set by tools .thanks !

Comment: Be careful with `!important` it can become very unmanageable if used too much. Although using it as an alternate class as a temporary style isn't as bad. I'm glad you have an acceptable solution, happy coding, sir.

Comment: zer00ne - yes , using at only one place ...I will seldom use it. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
$("table tr td").on("click",function(){
    $("td").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
})

})


//CSS

td.active{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Working Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/15797/
You just need to remove active class from every td and then add on the current clicked td.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine and this is what I was trying and I found other user provide the same solution before here : but somehow it is not working for me. My problem is, the code I am writing on top of existing tools generated code so definitely it is overriden by tools code somehow...   But appreciate your reply to doubleconfirm this is easiest way to do ... thanks ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072039/jquery-highlight-and-unhighlight-table-row

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. Keep Coding  :)

Comment: Actually I am trying to maniputing the code generated by Tools so below code works fine ... Unfortunately I can't use your code to refer from class and turn on and off ...basically tools existing code not liking it :   The only problem I am getting is : when I click other cell its not removing previous cell color : is there any other workaround with css and if I am missing something:  $(document).ready(function() {
  
 $("td.PTDC").on("click", function() {
 $( this ).css({
      "background-color": "#0093e0",
      "border": "10px"
    });   });

Comment: @pauldx I have posted another answer for you. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("table tr td.PTDC").on("click", function() {
    //This css will be applied across all table td's so make it specific
    $("table tr td").css({
      "background-color": "#fff",
      "border": "1px solid red"
    });
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "#0093e0",
      "border": "1px solid red"
    });
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/15797/

Updated fiddle as per your code. Check whether this satisfies. But make sure that i am applying the CSS on generic table tr td so make this specific